# How to access "browsing context" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to access **browsing context** in JavaScript?

**Update:** I'm reading HTML5 specification and there, it says that for each new tab, or new window, or iframe there is a notion of browsing context which is created by browser and each new document that you surf (each new link) would be stored and presented to users in this browsing context.

I just wonder if we have access to it. For example, a browsing context has a history and we can access that using `window.history`.

Comment: And by browsing context you mean exactly what?

Comment: This? http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context

Comment: I believe he is talking about the html5 notion of browsing context.

Comment: @Saeed: your question still isn’t particularly clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Nothing @Paul. Read the update :)

Comment: @Saeed: what update is that? You mean [Joseph’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942691/how-to-access-browsing-context-in-javascript/6942746#6942746)? That doesn’t really clarify your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes with the window object

see [what w3 says about it](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/browsers.html#windows)

You can use `window.top` to access the top most context for instance.

Comment: I'm reading the same text, but nowhere it says anything about any API to access browsing context. Anything I missing?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati "A browsing context is an environment in which Document objects are presented to the user." and "window.top Returns the WindowProxy for the top-level browsing context.". see how to access them in this section: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/browsers.html#navigating-nested-browsing-contexts-in-the-dom.